# Why is the __init__ method called twice when instantiating a class?

Tags: python

```py
class Color:
    def __new__(cls, obj=None, *args, **kwds):
        if cls is not Color:
            return object.__new__(cls)
        elif type(obj) is str:
            s = obj.lower()
            if s in ['r', 'red']:
                return Red(*args, **kwds)
            else:
                raise ValueError
        else:
            raise TypeError

    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        self.r = r
        self.g = g
        self.b = b

    def opposite(self):
        NotImplemented

    def brightness(self):
        NotImplemented

class Red(Color):
    def __init__(self, x=1):
        super().__init__(x, 0, 0)
```

In the code above, I hope that the baseclass `Color` can be called to instantiate its subclass objects. For example, I expect `Color('r')` to return an object of `Red` with `r=1` and `Color('r', 0.5)` to return a Red object with `r=0.5`. However, when I experiment with this, it turns out that

```py
red = Color('r')
print(red.r)
```

prints a string `'r'`! When I check the call stack, I find that the `__init__` method of the `Red` object has been called twice: the first time is `__init__(<Red object at ...>)` and the second time is `__init__(<Red object at ...>, 'r')`. Why does the second call happen?

The call stack is

```
__new__(<class '__main__.Color'>, 'r'):
    __new__(<class '__main__.Red'>):
    __new__(<class '__main__.Red'>) -> <__main__.Red object at 0x0000020AE612CF40>
    __init__(<__main__.Red object at 0x0000020AE612CF40>):
        __init__(<__main__.Red object at 0x0000020AE612CF40>, 1, 0, 0):
        __init__(<__main__.Red object at 0x0000020AE612CF40>, 1, 0, 0) -> None
    __init__(<__main__.Red object at 0x0000020AE612CF40>) -> None
__new__(<class '__main__.Color'>, 'r') -> <__main__.Red object at 0x0000020AE612CF40>
__init__(<__main__.Red object at 0x0000020AE612CF40>, 'r'):
    __init__(<__main__.Red object at 0x0000020AE612CF40>, 'r', 0, 0):
    __init__(<__main__.Red object at 0x0000020AE612CF40>, 'r', 0, 0) -> None
__init__(<__main__.Red object at 0x0000020AE612CF40>, 'r') -> None
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Simply because you initialized a full object in `__new__`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you call it twice implicitly.

The result of `__new__` has `__init__` invoked on it when you do `ClassName(...)`. Inside your `__new__`, you invoke normal object construction with `Red(...)`, which in turn invokes `__new__`, then `__init__` on the result and returns the new object. Then you return *that* object from the *original* `__new__` invocation, and it gets `__init__`-ed *again*.

To avoid the doubled `__init__`, explicitly use `__new__` inside `__new__`, not `Red()`, changing `return Red(*args, **kwargs)` to `return object.__new__(Red)`, and so on for the other two cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However I found that my approach still cannot work since after the `__new__` method of `Color` returns a `Red` object, the `__init__` method of `Red` is invoked and the str 'r' is passed as an argument. Hence `red.r` is still 'r' instead of a number. I tried to use a metaclass of `Color` to modify the behavior of `Color('r')` and it works :)

Comment: @JamesTZ: True, `'r'` would still be passed to `__init__`. Generally, it's best to stick to just `__new__` or `__init__`, not both. And if you do use both, you don't use different prototypes for each, for precisely the reason you saw.